# Python 3.5.2: from textblob import TextBlob : TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed Python 3.5.2 for windows - 32 bit. It includes PATH variable set procedure and required pip installation.

I'm trying to use TextBlob import for sentiment analysis, When I use import line in shell prompt it gives me TypeError : unorderable types str<> < int<>

```
from textblob import TextBlob
```

I'm aware of the new changes in Python 3.x regarding the type change, but here I haven't included any single line of code, just trying to use import.

[image: Python shell]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Resolved it.*** 
It was an issue with **nltk** lib. I have followed below commands and it worked.

**32-bit binary installation**

```
Install Numpy (optional): http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/ (the version that specifies pythnon3.4)
Install NLTK: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk
```

**Mac/Unix**

```
Install NLTK: run sudo pip install -U nltk
Install Numpy (optional): run sudo pip install -U numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is out on the version number,so maybe You could try to revise utils.py in the textblob folder.Add these script after the "try" in line 32:
**if not (x.isdigit()):**
   **x='0'**
so your codes will be:

```
def _parse_version(version_string):
version = []
for x in version_string.split('.'):
    try:
        if not (x.isdigit()):
            x='0'
        version.append(int(x))
        #print(x)
    except ValueError:
        # x may be of the form dev-1ea1592
        version.append(x)
return tuple(version)
```

Comment: Could please share utils.py, I'm not able to find " if not (x.isdigit()) " on line 32.